# Entity Framework 6 Include() not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've seen plenty of other threads on this issue but can't find an answer that addresses my exact problem. Apologies if I've overlooked it.

I have 2 types, Schedule and Job. I am trying to retrieve Schedule and include Job, but Job is never populated. I added the debug statement shown to view the SQL being produced and **it does** join to the Job table and select all the columns. I've pasted the generated SQL below.

When I manually run the SQL against the database it brings back rows with the columns from the Job table being populated i.e. there is definitely data there. However, that data is never used to create a Job object on the Schedule objects. What am I missing?

```
    public List<Schedule> GetActiveSchedules()
    {
        using (var context = new SchedulerContainer())
        {
            context.Database.Log = s => _logger.Debug(s);

            return context.Schedules
                .Where(s => s.IsEnabled)
                .Include(s => s.Job)
                .ToList();
        }
    }

SELECT 
[Extent1].[ScheduleId] AS [ScheduleId], 
[Extent1].[JobId] AS [JobId], 
[Extent1].[IsEnabled] AS [IsEnabled], 
[Extent1].[ValidFrom] AS [ValidFrom], 
[Extent1].[ValidTo] AS [ValidTo], 
[Extent1].[ScheduleTypeId] AS [ScheduleTypeId], 
[Extent1].[Schedule] AS [Schedule], 
[Extent1].[MaxDelay] AS [MaxDelay], 
[Extent1].[MaxRetries] AS [MaxRetries], 
[Extent1].[RetryInterval] AS [RetryInterval], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[NonWorkingDayStrategyId] AS [NonWorkingDayStrategyId], 
[Extent1].[Param] AS [Param], 
[Extent2].[JobId] AS [JobId1], 
[Extent2].[IJobImplementation] AS [IJobImplementation], 
[Extent2].[IsEnabled] AS [IsEnabled1], 
[Extent2].[Description] AS [Description1]
FROM  [scheduler].[Schedule] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [scheduler].[Job] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[JobId] = [Extent2].[JobId]
WHERE [Extent1].[IsEnabled] = 1
```

Below is what the Schedule and Job classes look like as requested by one of the commenters.

```
public partial class Schedule
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Schedule()
    {
        this.ScheduledJobs = new HashSet<ScheduledJob>();
        this.Dependencies = new HashSet<Dependency>();
        this.Groups = new HashSet<Group>();
    }

    public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ValidTo { get; set; }
    public ScheduleTypeEnum ScheduleTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Schedule1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MaxDelay { get; set; }
    public int MaxRetries { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> RetryInterval { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int NonWorkingDayStrategyId { get; set; }
    public string Param { get; set; }

    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
    public virtual ScheduleType ScheduleType { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ScheduledJob> ScheduledJobs { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Dependency> Dependencies { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual NonWorkingDayStrategy NonWorkingDayStrategy { get; set; }
}

public partial class Job
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Job()
    {
        this.Schedules = new HashSet<Schedule>();
        this.ScheduledJobs = new HashSet<ScheduledJob>();
        this.Dependencies = new HashSet<Dependency>();
    }

    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public string IJobImplementation { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<ScheduledJob> ScheduledJobs { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Dependency> Dependencies { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is `Job` a navigation property on `Schedule`? If yes, is it lazily loaded when called **without** `Include`?

Comment: Put the `Include()` statement before the `Where()` statement.

Comment: What do the `Schedule` and `Job` classes look like? What provider are you using?

Comment: Can you also show the `Job` entity? I assume you are claiming that the navigation property for `Job` entity is null in each item of the `List<Schedule>` that is returned?

Comment: @WiktorZychla There is a foreign key between Schedule and Job in the database. The edmx shows a line with a many-to-one relationship. I assume that's what you mean?

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 already tried that. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: @DavidG Please see the updated post for the classes. I'm using MS SQL Server.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I have updated the code to show the Job class. Yes the Job property is always null.